# Adding UIImage View in some cells

Tags: ios

I am trying to add UIImages in some prototype cells. I think what is going wrong is that I cannot seem to get rid of the UIImage View at places that I do not need it.

Comment: if you are reusing the cells-it'll happen, you need to manage it

Comment: @MidhunMP how should I do that? any suggestions?

Comment: @Jonathan Can you share the screenshot of your prototype cell, giving background color to labels. Even if the remote image is not shown, the placeholder image is showing, isn't it?

Comment: @Anupdas even the remote image is showing. Let me reconstruct the table and share it with you in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

   // Your code..

return cell;
```

}

Remove condition `if (cell == nil)`

hope this will solve your problem.

All the best !!!

Comment: If you are allocating the cell each time, then you don't need to dequeue a cell, so remove [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom cell with UIImageView for your image, load it into your tableView, then load your image into this UIImageView.
To create custom cell you need to create new class 'new file - objective-c class - subclass of UITableViewCell' and new empty Xib. Then you need to add to your xib a cell.

[image]

don't forget to show the class of this cell

[image]

I have created class named 'Cell', thats why i can see the cell class in my menunow in cell.h add all you need. For example UIImageView.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UITableViewCell {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *myView;

@end
```

Xib

[image]

(I have created class named 'Cell', thats why i can see the cell class in my menu)

Now you can add image to your cell in your class (Where is tableview)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

Cell *myCell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (myCell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CountCell"owner:self options:nil];
    myCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }
myCell.myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

return myCell;
}
```

Hope this will be useful. Sorry for my English )

Comment: Артур Бусаров, for some cells I need an image, for some I dont. (like Facebook)

Comment: you can set nil values for cells you don't

Comment: Артур Бусаров it doesnt seem to work. please have a look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

cell for row index is refreshed each time the table view is scrolled. If you could post your `cellForRowIndex` method, we can point out mistaks if any. My guess is in your `cellForRowIndex` method you are clearing the text and images somewhere and not filling in values to them due to some conditions. This must be a comment but sad I dont have the privileges