# List with 3 columns editable on the fly

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextview, xcode4.5

I want to add in an iOS App a list with 3 columns, but I also want that each field could be editable on the fly by clicking directly on it and when I press return it saves the field.
Currently I am using Xcode 4.6.1 and storyboard.

Here is the idea:

[image]

Because I am a beginner, I am asking you if there is a way to do that by using the UITableViewCell, UITextField and UITextView or there is something else to create this list faster.
Can you provide me some links with tutorials or similar, please?

Another question is: because each field (Label1,1; Label1,2; L1,3) will refer to the same object (eg.: cable; [size]1 meter; [diameter]1 cm), is it better to put each row in a NSMutuableArray or put everything in a SQLLite Database?

Hope in some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom cell. I answered how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331930/adding-uiimage-view-in-some-cells/15332284#15332284)

And add gesture recognizers for each object on the cell.
Change values and reload data.