# ios how to display multiple images in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

iOS how to display  multiple images in `UITableViewCell`.  the 1st image in the `UITableViewCell` should be fixed(*i.e., should not scroll off the view*).

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: are you want to display image like grid format

Comment: Look here, read my answer )
[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331930/adding-uiimage-view-in-some-cells/15332284#15332284

Answer (score 1):

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"S%1dR%1d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        /// You need to create UIImageView and add it to cell.contentView such like 

      UIImageView *imgView1 = [UIImageview alloc] init];
      imgeView1.fram = CGRectMake(@"AS U WANT") // set specific fram as u want.
      [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];// add as it is.
      .
      .
      .
      Create it as you want and add as it is.
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the main code for the UITableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        UIButton *imgV1=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        UIButton *imgV2=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        UIButton *imgV3=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        [imgV1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [imgV2 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [imgV3 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        HJManagedImageV *img1=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV1.frame.size.width, imgV1.frame.size.height)];
        HJManagedImageV *img2=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV2.frame.size.width, imgV2.frame.size.height)];
        HJManagedImageV *img3=[[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imgV3.frame.size.width, imgV3.frame.size.height)];
        img1.tag=img2.tag=img3.tag=10000;

        img1.backgroundColor=img2.backgroundColor=img3.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [imgV1 addSubview:img1];
        [imgV2 addSubview:img2];
        [imgV3 addSubview:img3];
    }

    int x=indexPath.row;
    x=x*3;

    UIButton *imgV1=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIButton *imgV2=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UIButton *imgV3=(UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    HJManagedImageV *img1=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV1 viewWithTag:10000];
    HJManagedImageV *img2=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV2 viewWithTag:10000];
    HJManagedImageV *img3=(HJManagedImageV*)[imgV3 viewWithTag:10000];

    [img1 clear];
    [img2 clear];
    [img3 clear];

    [imgV1 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    img1.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x]];
    [img1 showLoadingWheel];
    [GlobalCacheManager manage:img1];

    if((x+1) &gt;= self.tableArray.count){
        imgV2.hidden=imgV3.hidden=YES;
        [imgV2 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imgV3 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else if( (x+2)&gt;=self.tableArray.count) {
        img2.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1]];
        [img2 showLoadingWheel];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img2];
        imgV1.hidden=imgV2.hidden=YES;
        imgV3.hidden=YES;
        [imgV2 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [imgV3 setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [img2 showLoadingWheel];
        [img3 showLoadingWheel];
        img2.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1]];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img2];
        img3.url=[NSURL URLWithString:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+2]];
        [GlobalCacheManager manage:img3];
        imgV2.hidden=imgV3.hidden=NO;
        [imgV2 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+1] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [imgV3 setTitle:[self.tableArray objectAtIndex:x+2] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

You can download source code form [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?878z5b5lb3i0k01).

Comment: For more detail and step by step tutorial please refer this  http://sugartin.info/2011/09/02/custom-table-view-which-contains-more-then-one-images/ here.